# Insert html code in Twig

Tags: php, html, twig

I´m trying to insert dynamic links in a twig template, but when I render the page it shows the raw HTML.

I send the variables as an `array ('fact' => ['tag' => '<a href="loremipsum">tag</a>'])` for example) and then in the twig `{{ fact.tag }}`, but as mentioned it returns the raw tag.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: try `{{ fact.tag|raw }}`

Comment: or `('fact' => ['tag' => new \Twig_Markup('<a href="loremipsum">tag</a>','UTF-8')])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a Twigfiddle to show that `{{ fact.tag|raw }}` is the correct answer. It shows both with and without the raw filter:

https://twigfiddle.com/d4hc55